# Как пишется Кодекс

Tags: орфография

"Представители министерства заверили: реализация поправок в Градостроительный Кодекс к коллапсу не приведет".
Почему  слово Кодекс пишется с  большой буквы?

Answer (score 3):

С большой буквы:
1). Если КОДЕКС является заменой официального названия, например: Кодекс законов о труде РФ (далее Кодекс).

2). Название официального документа: Разрабатывается Кодекс законов о труде РФ.

В др. случаях пишется со строчной: Налоговый кодекс, Гражданский процессуальный кодекс и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Согласна с предыдущим ответом. Мне кажется, что в вашем примере - опечатка, должно быть: "... в Градостроительный кодекс..."